# Inverse Laplace Transform of a specific function which the poles are complicated

Tags: laplace-transform

I would like to ask if a close form (or even approximations) of the following inverse Laplace transform is know,

$$ {\cal L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+a)-ae^{-sL}}\right] = \;? $$

One usual thing to do is to identify the poles of the function and the inverse Laplace integral $\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma +i\infty}$ just give the sum of residues. However the function above has infinitely many poles and they are not elementary functions of $a$ and $L$.

Highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the use of Padé approximant for $e^{-sL}$ as

$$
e^{-sL} \approx \frac{1-\frac{L s}{2}+\frac{L^2 s^2}{10}-\frac{L^3 s^3}{120}+\cdots }{1+\frac{L s}{2}+\frac{L^2 s^2}{10}+\frac{L^3 s^3}{120}+\cdots}
$$

depending on the value of $L$ regarding $\{1, a\}$the expansion can be simply

$$
e^{-sL} \approx \frac{1-\frac{L s}{2} }{1+\frac{L s}{2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for that. However it is nor very useful since I know that there are infinitely many poles in the original form.

Comment: @user260822 In practical applications the results depend strongly  in the $L$ value regarding $1, a$